# PySpark error: AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name

Tags: apache-spark, exception, pyspark

I am trying to transform an entire df to a single vector column, using

`df_vec = vectorAssembler.transform(df.drop('col200'))`

I am being thrown this error:

`File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "col200" among (col1, col2..`

I looked around the internet and found out that the error could be caused because of some white spaces in the column headers. The problem is that there are around 1600 columns, and it's quite a task to check each one of them - especially for white spaces. How do I approach this? It's a df with around 800000 rows, FYI.

by doing df.printSchema(), I don't see any white spaces. Not leading at least. I am pretty positive that none of the column names have any spaces in between too.

At this point, I am totally blocked! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

That happened to me a couple of times, try this:

```
tempList = [] #Edit01
    for col in df.columns:
        new_name = col.strip()
        new_name = "".join(new_name.split())
        new_name = new_name.replace('.','') # EDIT
        tempList.append(new_name) #Edit02
print(tempList) #Just for the sake of it #Edit03

df = df.toDF(*tempList) #Edit04
```

The code trims and removes all whitespaces from every single column in your Dataframe.

Comment: It times out. The connection to Kernel breaks. It runs for about 10 minutes and the "No connection to Kernel" message comes up. FYI, there are like 1600 columns. I am doing this on an HDInsight Spark cluster. I tried with 4 nodes and 6. Same thing on both. The dataset is around 29 GB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I left is running regardless, and after like half hour of waiting, this error was thrown: `An error was encountered:
Invalid status code '400' from http://headnodehost:8998/sessions/0/statements/2 with error payload: "requirement failed: Session isn't active."`

Comment: Maybe you can do it step by step, because the error looks like a memory one. You can split the df.columns in, for example, 16 lists of 100 columns, and run it once at a time. PD: I dont think withColumnRenamed is memory expensive.

Comment: OK, I got it to work by not using `df = df.withColumnRenamed(col,new_name)` but something line `df_new = df.withColumnRenamed(col,new_name)`. Now, When I still try to perform do this `df_vec = vectorAssembler.transform(dropped_df)` it thrown the same error `AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name`. I am at my wit's end now.

Comment: Just wanted to know something: Can periods (.) or underscores cause this issue? It always fails at `col200` which is actually `EngineVersion_1.1.10401.0`. What part of that can cause issue?

Comment: Yes. Maybe that's the issue. I'll edit my post in order to remove the dots.

Comment: Thanks for that. So here's what happened. As before, `df = df.withColumnRenamed(col,new_name)` breaks the Kernel. Then I used `df_new` instead of `df` (in `df = df.withColumnRenamed(col,new_name)`) and that *seems to throw no errors*, BUT when I do `df_new.printSchema()` it shows the schema of `df` i.e. as it was before (with the dots and everything). Anything you can think of? So, `df_new = df.withColumnRenamed(col,new_name)` doesn't seem to be doing its thing.

Comment: Its because you are creating a new dataframe (df_new) with only one column renamed in every iteration. You need to do it as a put it in the code. Other than that, I suggest you to split df.columns in smaller lists and try the same code.

Comment: Nice !! Maybe you should edit my answer in a correct way, so other people with the same problem can solve it :)

Comment: Done that. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Perfect ! I approved your edit. Don't forget to mark these answer as valid :)

Comment: I suggest to change the replacement of `.` char for a special valid char (`-` for example) as keys like `M12.5` results in the same key as `M.125` and It'll throw an error saying that both keys are ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# remove spaces from column names
newcols = [col(column).alias(re.sub('\s*', '', column) \
for column in df.columns]

# rename columns
df = df.select(newcols).show()
```

EDIT: as a first step, if you just wanted to check which columns have whitespace, you could use something like the following:

```
space_cols = [column for column in df.columns if re.findall('\s*', column) != []]
```

Also, check whether there are any characters that are non-alphanumeric (or space):

```
non_alnum = [column for column in df.columns if re.findall('[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', column) != []]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. FYI, according to `space_cols = [column for column in df.columns if re.findall('\s*', column) != []]`, every column has a whitespace - evey 1640 of them! But then as I try `newcols = [col(column).alias(re.sub('\s*', '', column) \
for column in df.columns]`, then `df = df.select(newcols).show()` I am thrown the same error. Now, it is from what I *read on the internet (and also Stack Overflow)* that the error I am referring to occurs because of white spaces in the columns names. Could it is possible that it's happening due to something else totally?

Comment: what is the output of  ``` 'col200' in df.columns ``` ?

Comment: I ran `df = df.select('col1 AS `col1`').show()` (your code add a `` as a renamed character but I don't know if that should matter really), and the error was `'syntax error in attribute name: col1 AS `col1`;'`

Comment: also can we also get the output of df.printSchema() (top few lines or something) could help with debugging

Comment: Yes. That works. I mean, that displays the col1 correctly. I also tried that with a white space at the leading end and the trailing end, and was immediately thrown that same error. "cannot solve '`col1`' given input column: [... List of 1640 columns...]"

Comment: printSchema() -

root
 |-- col1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col5: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col6: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col7: double (nullable = true)

Comment: Hi, could you test that col200 exists as this was the original error?

Comment: The column exists. I am editing the column names as I do not have the leverage to show them, sorry. I can assure you that the names that I am replacing them with are formatted like how the original column name look like.

Comment: I can try replacing the col names with an underscore and check. What should I edit in `newcols = [col(column).alias(re.sub('\s*', '', column) for column in df.columns]`?

Comment: ok, so I added another check above to see if there are characters that are not alphanumeric (or space) in the columns, can you run and tell me what the output is? thanks

Comment: ``` 'col200' in df.columns ```? That's a True.

Answer (score 0):

`` or "" help identify the entire column.

```
df_vec = vectorAssembler.transform(df.drop('`col200`'))
```

or

```
df_vec = vectorAssembler.transform(df.drop("col200"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark gives an error for using "." in column names.

For example:
sepal.length

That's why I got an error. I removed the dots and used underscore and the errors went away.

For example:
sepal_length